# What could cause a computer's WiFi to be extremely slow?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

My `Dell Latitude E5400` laptop's WiFi is reasonable for general browsing, but when downloading large files it takes absurd amounts of time.

I can download a 4GB file over Ethernet in *8 minutes*, but the same file takes *1 hour 33 minutes* over WiFi. I've used both the built-in WiFi adapter and an external USB one.

I've used multiple different OS's (**Win 10, Win 7, Vista, even XP**) always with the same result.

Other (even older) machines on the same network can download 4GB files within 20 minutes.

Any ideas on what could cause this?

My laptop is sitting perhaps 3 feet from the access point. I never have more than 1 other device (my smartphone) connected at the same time. I've tried installing the official drivers for both adapters on each of the OSes, as well as using the Windows-detected driver, but the speed never improves. I also tried seitch between AES and TKIP as well switiching from b/g/n to b/g

When I run speed tests, I generally get ~9Mbps down at a ping of 70ms. HW diagnostics showed no problems with the built-in adapter, and the USB adapter is brand new.

Comment: Distance from the access point, number of connected devices, ISP throttling... Lots of options, what diagnostics have you performed? Please [edit] your question to include these.

Comment: Also, external interference. You don't own the airwaves, and others have the same right to them as you. A Wi-Fi device is designed, per the 802.11 standard, to share the airwaves with other Wi-Fi devices it can hear.

Comment: Do you have the make and model of the access point?

Comment: Keep in mind that WiFi will pretty much always be slower than Ethernet, because it is in inferior (in terms of power). Your wireless access point may also have problems handling large traffic like a file like that.

Comment: The router is an Xfinity-branded Arris TG862g

Comment: Wireless G would be significantly slower than ethernet...http://www.speedguide.net/faq/what-is-the-actual-real-life-speed-of-wireless-374

Answer (score 1):

Radio interference could cause it. Microwave ovens could interfere. Also try a different WiFi channel. If most neighbors are on channel 6, try channel 11 or 1. Try a direct line-of-site from the laptop to the base station. Metal walls or walls with wires embedded in them could block the signal. Check the router's admin page to see if you are connected to 'guest' mode, and if that mode has a bandwidth throttle limit.

Answer (score 0):

There are a large number of possible reasons, most likely with more then 1 coming in to play.

The first is the speed of the connection -

A typical modern computer has a gigabit connection - this means its maximum throughput is (very roughly) 1.25 megabyes per minute - which explains 8 minutes to download 4 gigs.

The (unrealistic) maximum of a WIFI connection varies depending on the type of connection - the TG862G is an 802.11n device, which means a maximum theortical speed of 300 megabits.

In reality, you never get anything close to the maximum speed on a WIFI network - this might be possible in a farraday cage with no other noise at all, but not in real life - Real speed will be a fraction of this - typically less then 80%, often way less.

Once you have taken that into account, you have very high (20-40%) overheads for negotiating and handling the WIFI connection.

If your computer has a cheaper WIFI interface, it may only handle 150megabit maximum connection, further slowing things.

It is probable you are not the only one using the WIFI spectrum - and this is slowing things down, ie interference from other devices.  Even if they don't show up on a scan, they are probably still there.  At the very least they are increasing the noise floor [ ie decreasing the signal strength ]